# Is it ok to access private members while doing same class comparison?

Tags: object-oriented, python

I am writing a class which basically is a wrapper around a dictionary with some extra functionality. This dictionary is stored as protected member `_store`. Now I am writing a `__eq__` method to compare objects of my class. The criterion is, if the underlying dictionaries are equal, the objects are equal, therefore the easiest approach would be:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self._store == other._store
```

But this entails accessing the protected members of a third object. Although this third object belongs to the same class as `self`. **Can we consider this breaking encapsulation??**

The other option is to do an item comparison between the two objects, which leads to a slightly less efficient and longer code (keys set comparison and check that the key-value pairs of one object equal the ones of the other object).

Comment: Whether encapsulation should apply to the *class* or to the *instance* is disputed. Many implementations imply the former, and many theoreticians prefer the latter. There is no consensus 'true answer'.

Comment: @KilianFoth: That's basically the difference between Abstract Data Types and Objects. I find it interesting that you put Haskell (which uses ADTs) in the pragmatic camp and Java (which uses Objects) in the theoreticians camp, though :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you tagged this with [python](/questions/tagged/python), I'll give you the Python perspective on this.

In Python, this is *entirely normal*. Attributes are not private, they are merely marked as 'internal', by convention, by using a leading underscore. So `_store` is something that is 'internal' to the class, just as the implementation of `__eq__` is an internal matter.

You are not breaking encapsulation here; you are merely providing a correct implementation of a hook method. Accessing `other._store` here is no different from accessing `self._store` in that respect. That's because Python is a pragmatic language, it is not a purist OO language (you can use functional and procedural paradigms whenever you feel that fits the problem space better, for example).

Note that you may want to return the `NotImplemented` singleton object for comparisons that your class doesn't support:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, MyClass):  # or not hasattr(other, '_store') perhaps
        return NotImplemented
    return self._store == other._store
```

Python would then delegate the test to the `other` object; if it doesn't implement the `__eq__` method or returns `NotImplemented` as well, then Python falls back to an identity test (`self is other`).

You'll find this pattern (using internal attributes in comparison hook methods) throughout the Python standard library. For example, all comparison methods for the [`decimal.Decimal()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) delegate to the [`Decimal._cmp()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/961f988eaa6a/Lib/decimal.py#l799), and the implementation for that method is based almost exclusively on using internal attributes and methods (`_is_special`, `_isinfinity()`, `_sign`, `_exp` and `_int`), accessed both on `self` and `other`.

Some more examples:

- [`fractions.Fraction.__eq__()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/961f988eaa6a/Lib/fractions.py#l527)
- [`sets.Set.__eq__()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/961f988eaa6a/Lib/sets.py#l131) (a precursor to the built-in `set` type, now deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

You tagged this with [object-oriented](/questions/tagged/object-oriented), so the answer is: no. The fact that objects *only* know about their *own* private implementation / representation and not about that of other objects *even of the same type* is the *defining* characteristic of object-oriented data abstraction as opposed to Abstract Data Types, where instances of an ADT *do* know about the private implementation of other instances of the same type.

If you are familiar with Java, then there is a simple way to think about this: `class` == ADT, `interface` == object.

This is beautifully explained in [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by William R. Cook.

Note that there's nothing wrong with ADTs per se, but a) as the name implies they rely on types (in the type-theoretic sense of the word, by which they mean *static* types), which Python doesn't have, and b) you specifically tagged the question with [object-oriented](/questions/tagged/object-oriented).

Note also that it is not quite easy to define what "two ADT instances of the same type" means in Python, since, after all, classes aren't types, ducks are.

Comment: You seem to imply that there is a well-defined, generally agreed-up solid definition of what "object-oriented" actually means... ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I'm implying that there is a somewhat "sane" definition of "object-oriented data abstraction", which is only a small part of OO.

Comment: @FredOverflow: let me clarify. I am only talking about *data abstraction* here, not overall system design. And "sane" was a misnomer, I meant "useful". A definition of object-oriented data abstraction that is identical to the definition of an Abstract Data Type is useless, because the two are *clearly* different. Realizing this was the brilliance of Simula, and not understanding that Simula actually had invented an entirely new abstraction mechanism and not just a nice way of writing ADTs, is the bane of languages like C++, Java and C#.

Comment: I've heard people say that focusing too much on Alan Kay's interpretation of OO doesn't give enough credit to Dahl and Nygaard. But actually, by pretending that Objects are basically just ADTs with different syntax, you are basically implying that Dahl and Nygaard didn't invent anything. How's *that* for not giving credit? Alan Kay OTOH says that Dahl and Nygaard were brilliant, but everybody ignored their brilliance and didn't realize that they had actually invented something profoundly new. (Well … everybody except the guys at Xerox, obviously … he's not *that* modest :-D )

Comment: Saying that the class-based approach to object-orientation is equivalent to a different syntax for declaring Abstract Data Types is an overly reductionist argument, which entirely ignores the fact that inheritance (whether you use implementation inheritance or type inheritance) makes a significant difference in the capabilities of the two paradigms. Inheritance is the defining factor of object-orientation, not encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, it is very interesting but actually Martijn's answer helps me solve my problem more directly, therefore I chose it (the question falls in a grey area between python OOP and OOP pure theory). You have provided good material for me to read and learn :)